# Why are monochrome red OLED display hard to come by

Tags: oled

It looks like the majority of monochrome OLED display modules available on the market are white, orange/yellow, green or blue. There seems to be only a very limited amount of red displays available.

Are there any technical limitations preventing or making the production of red OLED displays more difficult?